# SSRS 2017 Web.config permissions

Tags: reporting-services, reporting-services-2016

I have run into an issue with my SSRS 2017 report manager. I have implemented the sample found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/blob/master/CustomSecuritySample/README.md) and it all seems to work except from the web portal (the server is fine). I have found the solution is that the service user needs to have write permissions to the web.config to copy the machinekey from RSReportingServices.config.

How can I circumvent this? I have tried manually writing to the web.config but the rshostingservice still tries to sync the keys and fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want able to circumvent the need of write permissions. I solved my issue by granting write permission to the service that runs ssrs. i used the below code to bestow the required permissions

```
        try
        {
            var fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(Path);
            var user = ServiceUserDetails();
            fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.Write,
                AccessControlType.Allow));
            fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.Read,
                AccessControlType.Allow));
            fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
                AccessControlType.Allow));
            File.SetAccessControl(Path, fileSecurity);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Error",
                $@"Unable to set permissions for {Path}. Please ensure service has write permission");
        }
```